# how to create a fixed footer with HTML on bootstrap

Tags: html, css

In the below html the footer is not appearing fixed at the bottom of the page.

How do i fix this?

I have designed a sample website with a log and a menu in the middle. and now i need to add text to the page, but the footer needs to be stationary at the bottom. but currently the footer is rendering next to the text.
Can any one please help me

**html**

```
<div  style="margin-top: 578px; font-size: 31px; max-width:100%;margin:0 auto; float:left; color: orange;">UNDER CONSTRUCTION</div>
<footer>
<div class="footer">
    <div class="container">
        <p>Address:- D-000, Text Text, Text. Text, Text (Text), Text-000 0000, Text <br>
Mobile : +91 000-000-0000 Phone : + 0000 0000 0000 Fax : + 0000 0000 0000 <br>
Email: abc@gmail.com<br>
Copyright &copy; 2015 OLISVELL, Inc.</p>

    </div>
</div>
</footer>
```

**style**

```
.footer {
color:#EEEEE; 
font: italic 12px/30px Arial;
position: relative;
 width: 100%; 
  float: left;
 bottom: 0; 
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  min-height: 43px;

background:#000000;
}

.footer p{

color:#ffffff;

font-weight:600;
float:left;
text-align:left;

}
```

Comment: Following link may help you http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer-navbar

Comment: add class footer <footer class="footer">. try this

Comment: you got solution or not you deleted your comments ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the body element is the footer parent if not, then the styles applied to the body needs to be applied to the parent.

```
body{
  height:100%;
  position:relative;
}

footer{
  width:100%;
  position:absolute;  // or fixed, depending on your use
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following styles to the footer class:

```
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0; 
}
```

See the fiddle: "http://jsfiddle.net/fw3dd4gd/"

Answer (score 1):

You could alternatively use:

```
.footer {
    position:fixed; 
    bottom:0;
}
```

If you want the footer fixed to the viewport window and always visible.

Answer (score 1):

See this example :http://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/06rggkLb/1/

[Difference between absolute and fixed position](https://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/)

> In your example your css correct only you need to change position. i.e
>   **position: relative to position: fixed**

And you are using bootstrap see this bootstrap solution

http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer/ they are using position: absolute

If you use absolute then make sure your footer is not in any div which has some position. so if you apply position absolute then place your footer in body

```
.footer {
    color:#EEEEE;
    font: italic 12px/30px Arial;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    bottom: 0;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    min-height: 43px;
    background:#000000;
}
```

Comment: @care567 use   z-index: 9;  in footer class i see your carousel  window overlap footer

Comment: without scroll i want to be fixed at the bottom ? i think you have to place footer in bottom means last of all contain when you scroll dont want to show with scroll ?